# Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с такой проблемой: я записываю данные в *.csv файл при помощи writerow(), но все переменные записываются в один столбик

Tags: python-3.x, файлы, excel

Вот скрипт:

```
import csv
name_1 = 'Anna'
name_2 = 'Victor'
with open('34.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow([name_1, name_2])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Скриншот из Excel'а

Comment: Вы все правильно записали. Вы ОТКРЫЛИ неверно. `csv` - это текстовый формат. И разделители ячеек и строк там могут различаться. При открытии вам просто нужно было указать что разделителем значений ячеек является `запятая`

Comment: там где-то на вкладке `Данные` в `Инструментах` можно выбрать разделитель

Comment: Да, спасибо, я выбрал Данные -> Текст по столбцам и там выбрал разделитель по запятым

Comment: Отлично! Вопрос этот можете удалить, а то кто-то еще начнет пытаться решение какое-то искать :-)

Comment: В случае чего - пишите )

Comment: Я понял, как сделать это в excel'e, но если надо добавлять данные в файл и они автоматически должны переноситься в следующий столбец. По стандарту, в excel'е символом переноса является знак табуляции. Я решил оформить это в питоне, но никак не получается \n поместить между двумя объектами списка. Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты используешь функцию writerow(), которая нацелена на один столбик, используй функцию writerows() для внесения данных в разные столбики

```
import csv
name_1 = 'Anna'
name_2 = 'Victor'
with open('34.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows([name_1, name_2])
```